# Selenium - Write Page Element Out to a File

Tags: file, selenium, output

I have a script developed in Selenium IDE for Firefox (Windows 7, FF 25.01 IDE 2.4.0).

It works, so far.  But, I'd like to record a page element from the page/query it runs, out to a text file.  Basically, the page it loads, has a script, which outputs various time elements.... (below).

```
    <div id="page_timing_div" class="timingDiv" style="visibility: visible;">
<img class="pointerhand" width="12" height="12" src="images/response_time.gifx" title="Response time(ms): 9882, network: 6537, browser: 2543, server: 802">
<span class="timing_span" style="display: inline;">
Response time(ms): 9882, network: 6537, server: 802, 
<a class="timing_span">browser: 2543</a>
<span style="position:relative; width: 1px;">
<span style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px">
<span id="page_timing_details"></span>
```

I want to record the date/time the test script was run, and the timing outputs to a file.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you show some of the code you use to get that element(s)? And, if possible, more of the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't using the IDE write out to a file on the filesystem during a test run.

What you could do is create a webservice that records this information somewhere and have the IDE test hit that webservice passing it all the required information and just do this at the end of the test.

Edit: You are able to save the output to a file using plugin for the IDE but don't know if its triggerable from within a run and it outputs everything. (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/?src=collection&collection_id=be0f59fe-504e-419d-8024-7a6282c7d07b)

You could create a Selenium IDE plugin to do what you want also. (I imagine its possible since you'd add a new command that would do what you want)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. You just need to create some javascript function using mozilla (firefox) addons API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons, save this function in selenium core extension file http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp and add this extension into Selenium IDE.

Sample function to write text file:

```
    // ==================== File Writer ====================
Selenium.prototype.doWriteData = function(textToSave, location)
{   
    var data = textToSave;
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(location);
    var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
    foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
    var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);
    converter.init(foStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
    converter.writeString(data);
    converter.close();
}
```

Read is simple to do as well, just add another function, something like "doReadData" more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O